# ASP.NET Jquery Post Error When Published

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis

My site on Visual Studio 2015. It is work correctly on visual studio debug on my computer. When I publish project in IIS, second post get error.

Comment: what do you mean by _MySql server_?

Comment: I use mysql database on my project.

Comment: Where exactly is that error coming from?  The ones you're showing only go up to "4__".

Comment: I am so sorry. Wrong code. Edited.

Comment: @CircasCreed: Ok, so there was an error response from the server.  It sounds like that response doesn't have a `.message` property.  What does it have?  What is the actual response from the server?  Check your browser's network debugging tools to see the entire response.  If it indicates a server-side error, debug your server-side code to determine information about that error.

Comment: @David  When I debug before publish it is work fine. How can I debug on server side?

Comment: @CircasCreed: First determine what you can about the nature of the error from the response.  It's possible all the information you need is there.  If it isn't, you may need to add some logging and debug tracing to the application and re-publish to capture more information about the error.

Comment: @David Thank you. I will.

Comment: Also, IE and Chrome both have "F12" debugger tools which can be used to see the requests and responses to/from the server. Might help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION : I write file on a folder. I need set full control permission to folder for IIS_IUSRS.